# Dynamic Proxy Creating WCF Services using C#

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

Using C# How do i create the Dynamic Proxy.

My Requirment is

Same as WCFTestClient how it workes.

1. Enter the SVC Url in the TextBox
2. Get all the Methods
3. Select one of the Method and Pass the Argument
4. In Result View it should return the response.

FYI, i tried using the ServiceDescriptionImporter and CodeNamespace. In that i am getting the following error

"Cannot find definition for xxxx.Gxxx.Services/Contracts/:IUtilitiesService.  Service Description with namespace xxx.Gxxx.Services/Contracts/ is missing.Parameter name: name"

I googled it and got it one link from our Stackoverflow. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vipulmodi/archive/2006/11/16/dynamic-programming-with-wcf.aspx

In that it shows some link to download the Library and but it says

"The Archive Gallery has been retired.".

Can anybody help me.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to check Mike Taulty's blog with the below link and check out its video sections. it has said everything in details. And for what you seek I recommend to watch the Hello world example.

[link](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2006/09/13/windows-communication-foundation-videos.aspx)

Hope it helps

Comment: Nothing specific on Dymanic Proxy H.A. And more over if i click anylink it says "We are sorry, the page you requested cannot be found.". Message.